# $y = 3\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})/x$ find $y'(1/4)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y =   3\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})/x$                find $y'(1/4)$

my work is that

y'= (x*$    ('\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x}))+\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x}) *1$)/(x)^2

my problem how to Derivative $  \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will do implicit differentiation instead. we have $$y = \frac{3 \sin^{-1}\sqrt x}x $$ we will turn this into $$\sin^2\left(\frac{xy}{3}\right) = x.$$  differencing the last equation gives 
$$2 \sin\left(\frac{xy}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{xy}{3}\right)\frac13\left(x\, dy + y \, dx\right) = dx \tag 1$$ now we will subb $x = \frac14, y = 2\pi, xy/3 =\pi/6 $ gives us 
$$2\times \frac12 \times \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \times \frac 13\left(\frac14 dy+2\pi dx\right) = dx \to \frac{dy}{dx} = 8(\sqrt 3 - \pi) $$

i hope i have not made any arithmetic errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do this: $$\arcsin(\sin x) = x \implies \arcsin'(\sin x) \cos x = 1 \implies \arcsin'(\sin x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}.$$ Meaning that $\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Now you use the chain rule and the quotient rule. $$y = \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{x})}{x} \implies \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x}^2)}}x - \arcsin(\sqrt{x})}{x^2}.$$ I won't simplify this so you can compare with $$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$ and see how things fit in the formula. Now plug $x = 1/4$ and you're done.